Cannot login to desktop environment Debian 12 - "authentication error"
I accidentally logged myself out of Debian 12 and I can't log back in through the GUI/desktop environment.
I can't select the password box or type anything, and occasionally "authentication error" will flash underneath the password box.
This is pretty sudden. Everything was working perfectly fine earlier until I must've hit a keyboard shortcut that logged me out in the middle of typing. I've done this before, but this time I can't log back in.
I've done a little bit of research, and I've managed to Ctrl+Alt+F3 and login as root, but I'm not really sure what to do from there.
I've already tried apt-get -f install, as per the recommendation in another thread, and I guess this would fix "partially installed" packages, but it spat out 0 upgraded, 0 installed, etc. so I guess that's not the problem.
I have almost no valuable Linux experience, so I'll try whatever is suggested and give any information requested, but I might need some stuff explained like I'm five. My desktop environment is GNOME, by the way.

The login page is your display manager (often gdm3).  If you can't select the password box or type anything, it sounds like gdm3 might have a problem.  Maybe systemctl restart gdm3?  Check if there's something funny in /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf or ~/.dmrc like a bad Session= field.
